Authentication implementation using clerk in NextJs
I am working on frontend using tailwind css  and for authentication i am using clerk .
but after  creating middleware  i am getting error
Server Error
TypeError: _react.default.createContext is not a function

There may be a version mismatch between your react and react-dom dependencies or an issue with how React is being imported in your project.

i just cloned this project from github .is there any other way to identify exact issue .

looks like you are creating context in the server side, maybe that's the issue? "use client"; is needed somewhere in your code...
